# Run .exe by the use of application server

Tags: java, glassfish, runtime

It it possible to package .exe file inside java jar and add this jar to deployment assembly of a project than run this exe by the use of :

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec();`
I was trying to run this exe after getting it's path inside glassfish domain by the use of class loader but actually this exe is packaged inside the jar which prevent windows from executing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to extract it from the *jar* first:

```
    FileOutputStream fos=null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {

        is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("path to your exe inside the jar");
        fos = new FileOutputStream("destination path on host file system");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = is.read(buffer)) > -1)
            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);

    }
    finally
    {

        if (is != null)
            is.close();
        if (fos != null)
            fos.close();
    }
```

Then, run it on the host file system with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

Comment: extracting is overhead since it contain a lot of related dll and resources. i prefer to add the exe and related dll to the project (without the use of jar)instead of extracting it.